# Dynamically adding html to panel

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am designing an app in sencha touch2. I have a panel object in my JS file. I need to dynamically set the text/html for this component. The store for this component is defined at the application level. Following is the thing I worked out:

```
Ext.define('class_name',{

....

config : {

  pnlObj : null,

  ...
}

initialize : function() {

    this.config.pnlObj = Ext.create('Ext.Panel');
    var store = Ext.data.Storemanager.lookup('some_store');
    store.on('load',this.loadStore,this);
    this.setItems([{
     //some items here
     {
     flex : 2,
//   id : 'somepnl',

     config : this.config.pnlObj
}

}]);

},

loadStore : function(store, rec) {

     var text = rec.get('text');
     var panel = this.config.pnlObj;
//   var panel = Ext.getCmp('somepanl');
     panel.setHtml(text);

}


});
```

When I inspect the inspect the element using Firebug console, I can find the panel added there. But I am not able to set the html dynamically. no html text is set there. I tried adding it using panel.add() & panel.setItems() method which doesn't work. If I give an id to that panel(somepanel here) and try to access it using Ext.getCmp('smpanel') then in that case it works fine. I have found that using Ext.getCmp() is not a good practice and want to avoid it as it might somewhere break my code in the future.

I guess the way I am instantiating the panel object is creating some issue. Can someone suggest the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 5):

The recommended way to manipulate your components in Sencha Touch 2 is using **controller**, through `refs` and `control` configs. For example, your panel has a config like this: `xtype:'myPanel'`, then in your controller:

```
refs: {
   myPanel: 'myPanel'
}

control:{
   myPanel: {
     on_an_event: 'set_html_for_my_panel'
   }
}
```

Lastly, define your function:

```
set_html_for_my_panel: function()
{
   this.getMyPanel().setHtml('my_updated_html');
}
```

P/S: Behind the scene, Sencha Touch 2 uses `Ext.ComponentQuery` for `refs` in controllers